# Display loading icon when loading another form

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro

I'm using [MetroFramework](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui) to write a C# Metro WinForm project, and I'm having issues getting a loading icon (class `metroProgressSpinner`) to display when creating a new form.

The following screenshot is a code snippet:

[image]

The following gif shows the current result:

[image]

When I remove create Form code

> _editor = new Editor(this);
>
> _editor.Show();

The icon works well

Comment: Presumably the spinner gets updated on a timer whose tick event isn't being fired because the GUI thread is tied up opening the second form.

Comment: I liked how you used a gif to explain.

Comment: @stuartd no, the wait cursor work perfect, but my recorder software not capture it stability

Comment: @adv12 i use the spinner from MetroFramework [link](https://github.com/dennismagno/metroframework-modern-ui)

Comment: @adv12 you are right, that spinner update on a timerTick. Can I keep it's event when loading another form?